# Monitor isn't printing in intended lines

Tags: c, arduino

I wrote a short code for an Arduino connected to a button that is supposed to count the number of times the button has been pressed and print it in two forms: binary and decimal.

When writing the following source code:

```c
int x=0;                
void setup() {
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);           
  Serial.println("DEC");        
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("BIN");      
  Serial.print("\t");           
}
void loop()  {
  while (digitalRead(2) == 0);
  x++;                  
  Serial.print(x, DEC);     
  Serial.print("\t");           
  Serial.println(x, BIN);       
  Serial.print("\t");           
  while (digitalRead(2) == 1);
}
```

The monitor printed the text almost intended, but instead of it being printed as intended:

```
decimal < decimal num >
binary  < binary num >
```

The monitor printed it like this:

```
decimal
binary< decimal num >
< binary num >
```

Comment: Please verify your use of `Serial.print` and `Serial.println`. The code you posted above will print neither of your outputs.

Comment: 1) Arduino is C++, not C. 2) Your code does what you ask it to do, you seems not quite know the differences between `Serial.print()` versus `Serial.println()` yet, which means you should read [the example](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/cs/language/functions/communication/serial/print/) provided on `Serial.print()` reference page.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are using

```
Serial.println("DEC");
```

Not

```
Serial.print("DEC");
```

println() add a new line at the end automatic